# Save and load an image in my phone gallery using coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, core-data

I have a problem here.i need to add details of a person using coredata in my app.i need to store an image also with each persons detail.and also i need to display these details in a table view in the next view controller.i could save and display all other details except for the image.how can i save and display that using coredata?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the images in your Xcode project and save the image name and path in core data and reference them in image view when needed

Answer (score 0):

Add delegate  to your .h file

use below code to open Photo Gallery

```
    UIImagePickerController *picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    picker.delegate=self;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

use this delegate event to get the selected image and save it to local directory,

```
#pragma mark - Imagepicker delegate
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)imagePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *origImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    //Code to save image in local directory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];

    UIImage *image = origImage.image; // origImage is my image from photo library
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO]; 

    [imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

use below code to load image from gallery

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *ImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
  UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:ImagePath];
```

here in img you can get your image